# jQuery How To Add a Variable

Tags: jquery

I am a novice in jQuery. I am using some open source code which portions appear below. All I want to do with the code is add a variable ('testVar') that a subsequent function call can handle. Can someone correct my code because the variable definition and handler does not work. Everything works except the testVar variable.

```
$('#default').countdown({
    until: new Date(2011, 6, 15, 12, 30, 0),
    testVar: 'Testing',
    onTick: displayVariable
});

function displayVariable() {
    $(this).text(testVar);
}
```

Thank you.

**EDIT:** @Pixeltweak...per your request. The code is below. I simply want to create a text phase that I display on my web page. I need to create a var to do that with.

```
$(function () {

    // override regional defaults
    $.countdown.setDefaults({
        labels: ['years', 'months', 'weeks', 'days', 'hours', 'minutes', 'seconds'],
        labels1: ['year', 'month', 'week', 'day', 'hour', 'minute', 'second']
    });

    // Round #1 Start Times -- note each Date() must match the 'lockout' column in _playoff_bracket:matches 
    $('#defaultCountdown_01').countdown({
        until: new Date(2011, 4 - 1, 13, 19, 30, 0),
        serverSync: serverTime,
        significant: 2,
        layout: 'This Pick Closes in: {d<}{dn} {dl} {d>}{h<}{hn} {hl} {h>}{m<}{mn} {ml} {m>}{s<}{sn} {sl} {s>}',
        expiryUrl: '/nhl/playoffs/myAccount.html',
        onTick: additionalFormatting
    });
    $('#defaultCountdown_02').countdown({
        until: new Date(2011, 4 - 1, 14, 19, 30, 0),
        serverSync: serverTime,
        significant: 2,
        layout: 'This Pick Closes in: {d<}{dn} {dl} {d>}{h<}{hn} {hl} {h>}{m<}{mn} {ml} {m>}{s<}{sn} {sl} {s>}',
        expiryUrl: '/nhl/playoffs/myAccount.html',
        onTick: additionalFormatting
    });
    $('#defaultCountdown_03').countdown({
        until: new Date(2011, 4 - 1, 14, 19, 0, 0),
        serverSync: serverTime,
        significant: 2,
        layout: 'This Pick Closes in: {d<}{dn} {dl} {d>}{h<}{hn} {hl} {h>}{m<}{mn} {ml} {m>}{s<}{sn} {sl} {s>}',
        expiryUrl: '/nhl/playoffs/myAccount.html',
        onTick: additionalFormatting
    });
    $('#defaultCountdown_04').countdown({
        until: new Date(2011, 4 - 1, 13, 19, 0, 0),
        serverSync: serverTime,
        significant: 2,
        layout: 'This Pick Closes in: {d<}{dn} {dl} {d>}{h<}{hn} {hl} {h>}{m<}{mn} {ml} {m>}{s<}{sn} {sl} {s>}',
        expiryUrl: '/nhl/playoffs/myAccount.html',
        onTick: additionalFormatting
    });
    $('#defaultCountdown_05').countdown({
        until: new Date(2011, 4 - 1, 13, 22, 0, 0),
        serverSync: serverTime,
        significant: 2,
        layout: 'This Pick Closes in: {d<}{dn} {dl} {d>}{h<}{hn} {hl} {h>}{m<}{mn} {ml} {m>}{s<}{sn} {sl} {s>}',
        expiryUrl: '/nhl/playoffs/myAccount.html',
        onTick: additionalFormatting
    });
    $('#defaultCountdown_06').countdown({
        until: new Date(2011, 4 - 1, 14, 22, 0, 0),
        serverSync: serverTime,
        significant: 2,
        layout: 'This Pick Closes in: {d<}{dn} {dl} {d>}{h<}{hn} {hl} {h>}{m<}{mn} {ml} {m>}{s<}{sn} {sl} {s>}',
        expiryUrl: '/nhl/playoffs/myAccount.html',
        onTick: additionalFormatting
    });
    $('#defaultCountdown_07').countdown({
        until: new Date(2011, 4 - 1, 13, 19, 0, 0),
        serverSync: serverTime,
        significant: 2,
        layout: 'This Pick Closes in: {d<}{dn} {dl} {d>}{h<}{hn} {hl} {h>}{m<}{mn} {ml} {m>}{s<}{sn} {sl} {s>}',
        expiryUrl: '/nhl/playoffs/myAccount.html',
        onTick: additionalFormatting
    });
    $('#defaultCountdown_08').countdown({
        until: new Date(2011, 4 - 1, 13, 22, 30, 0),
        serverSync: serverTime,
        significant: 2,
        layout: 'This Pick Closes in: {d<}{dn} {dl} {d>}{h<}{hn} {hl} {h>}{m<}{mn} {ml} {m>}{s<}{sn} {sl} {s>}',
        expiryUrl: '/nhl/playoffs/myAccount.html',
        onTick: additionalFormatting
    });

    // Round #2 Start Times -- note each Date() must match the 'lockout' column in _playoff_bracket:matches 
    $('#defaultCountdown_09').countdown({
        until: new Date(2011, 4 - 1, 29, 19, 0, 0),
        serverSync: serverTime,
        significant: 2,
        layout: 'This Pick Closes in: {d<}{dn} {dl} {d>}{h<}{hn} {hl} {h>}{m<}{mn} {ml} {m>}{s<}{sn} {sl} {s>}',
        expiryUrl: '/nhl/playoffs/myAccount.html',
        onTick: additionalFormatting
    });
    $('#defaultCountdown_10').countdown({
        until: new Date(2011, 4 - 1, 30, 15, 0, 0),
        serverSync: serverTime,
        significant: 2,
        layout: 'This Pick Closes in: {d<}{dn} {dl} {d>}{h<}{hn} {hl} {h>}{m<}{mn} {ml} {m>}{s<}{sn} {sl} {s>}',
        expiryUrl: '/nhl/playoffs/myAccount.html',
        onTick: additionalFormatting
    });
    $('#defaultCountdown_11').countdown({
        until: new Date(2011, 4 - 1, 28, 21, 0, 0),
        serverSync: serverTime,
        significant: 2,
        layout: 'This Pick Closes in: {d<}{dn} {dl} {d>}{h<}{hn} {hl} {h>}{m<}{mn} {ml} {m>}{s<}{sn} {sl} {s>}',
        expiryUrl: '/nhl/playoffs/myAccount.html',
        onTick: additionalFormatting
    });
    $('#defaultCountdown_12').countdown({
        until: new Date(2011, 4 - 1, 29, 22, 0, 0),
        serverSync: serverTime,
        significant: 2,
        layout: 'This Pick Closes in: {d<}{dn} {dl} {d>}{h<}{hn} {hl} {h>}{m<}{mn} {ml} {m>}{s<}{sn} {sl} {s>}',
        expiryUrl: '/nhl/playoffs/myAccount.html',
        onTick: additionalFormatting
    });

    // Round #3 Start Times -- note each Date() must match the 'lockout' column in _playoff_bracket:matches 
    $('#defaultCountdown_13').countdown({
        until: new Date(2011, 5 - 1, 14, 20, 0, 0),
        serverSync: serverTime,
        significant: 2,
        layout: 'This Pick Closes in: {d<}{dn} {dl} {d>}{h<}{hn} {hl} {h>}{m<}{mn} {ml} {m>}{s<}{sn} {sl} {s>}',
        expiryUrl: '/nhl/playoffs/myAccount.html',
        onTick: additionalFormatting
    });
    $('#defaultCountdown_14').countdown({
        until: new Date(2011, 5 - 1, 15, 20, 0, 0),
        serverSync: serverTime,
        significant: 2,
        layout: 'This Pick Closes in: {d<}{dn} {dl} {d>}{h<}{hn} {hl} {h>}{m<}{mn} {ml} {m>}{s<}{sn} {sl} {s>}',
        expiryUrl: '/nhl/playoffs/myAccount.html',
        onTick: additionalFormatting
    });

    // Round #4 Start Times -- note each Date() must match the 'lockout' column in _playoff_bracket:matches 
    $('#defaultCountdown_15').countdown({
        until: new Date(2011, 6 - 1, 1, 20, 0, 0),
        test: 'Testing',
        serverSync: serverTime,
        significant: 2,
        layout: 'This Pick Closes in: {d<}{dn} {dl} {d>}{h<}{hn} {hl} {h>}{m<}{mn} {ml} {m>}{s<}{sn} {sl} {s>}',
        expiryUrl: '/nhl/playoffs/myAccount.html',
        onTick: additionalFormatting
    });

    // additional hightlighting for more than 1-day and within last-hour of pick
    function additionalFormatting(periods) {
        if ($.countdown.periodsToSeconds(periods) >= 86400) {
            $(this).text('You have until Wednesday at 8:00pm ET to finalize this pick');
            //$(this).text($(this).countdown.test);
            $(this).removeClass('hideIt');
            //$(this).addClass('hideIt'); // greater than or equal to 1-day (2011-05-28 changed this method for one above)
        }
        else $(this).removeClass('hideIt'); // less than 24 hours
        if ($.countdown.periodsToSeconds(periods) < 60) { // less than 1-minute
            $(this).addClass('highlightBold'); // change font-weight to bold
            //$(this).countdown('change', 'significant', 1); // eliminate minutes block -- does not work as I hoped for
            //$(this).countdown('change', 'layout', 'This Pick Closes in: {sn} {sl}'); // eliminate minutes block -- does not work either
        }
        else if ($.countdown.periodsToSeconds(periods) < 3600) $(this).addClass('highlight'); // less than 1-hour
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
$('#default').countdown({
    until: new Date(2011, 6, 15, 12, 30, 0),
    onTick: displayVariable
}).data("testVar","Testing");

function displayVariable() {
    $(this).text($(this).data("testVar"));
}
```

Comment: The problem is that displayVariable() actually has a parameter defined to it so the true and complete function statement is additionalFormatting(periods). You can see the exact script posted herein

Comment: OK...why can't you just have a function which *doesn't* take a parameter, and then turn around and call the one that does? E.g.,     call additionalFormatting($(this).data("period"))?

Comment: @aquinas. In my script, I have 15 $('#default').countdown({}); segments. Each of them call function additionalFormatting(periods). Inside additionalFormatting(periods) I only want to override the $(this).text() when the countdown is not within the last 24 hours. So I am trying to define and set a variable inside each of the $('#default').countdown({}); that comes into play when the countdown is greater than 24 hours.

Comment: Oh, I thought you were saying *you* were passing something to the function. Now I see it's just via the callback. So, again, I'm not certain why you can't have this (just humor me and try this :))

$('#defaultCountdown_15').countdown({
/*Snip*/
})

.data("test","Testing");

And then in your function use $(this).data("test")

Comment: Ok @aquinas -- I will definitely try your suggestion. But it will have to wait until the morning -- late here. I'll post my tests here in the AM.

Comment: Awesome @aquinas...Your solution worked perfectly. I will post my script as an answer with the label Code from aquinas (success for me)

Comment: Interesting behaviour @aquinas -- the script renders the text phrase from the original open source system, and then ~1 second later the text's container reverts to my override in the browser. Ultimately I achieve what I am after and I can live with the delayed swapping of the text. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you aren't passing testVar into the displayVariable function. I would suggest trying something like this.

```
$('#default').countdown({
    until: new Date(2011, 6, 15, 12, 30, 0),
    onTick: function() {
        $('#myElement').text('Testing');
    }
});
```

Comment: Well, the code is excerpted portions from the overall script. So the function displayVariable() needs to stay as is (a) because there is more to it than what I presented and (b) that function gets called from other parts of the script.

Comment: + oned for the refactorisation, though I may just change last line to  $(this).text('Testing');

Comment: You actually downvoted the good samaritan that _handed you a decent solution for the partial piece of code you initially showed_? Hmmm.

Comment: Stef, you plused but did not read my comment. I am truly sorry if I offended you. I tried  plusing it back for you but S.O. won't let me.

Comment: Ok, so I don't upset people graciously trying to help me -- Seth and Stef -- I am stepping through everyone's recommended code. But honestly, given I know little about jQuery (at this point in my technological development) but I do know JavaScript quite well, I am at a loss as to what I do with Seth's $('#myElement').text('Testing'); in my called function.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using the [jQuery Countdown](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html) plugin, which doesn't appear to support abitrary options like that. You're better off building the argument into the function:

```
$('#default').countdown({
    until: new Date(2011, 6, 15, 12, 30, 0),
    onTick: displayVariable
});

function displayVariable() {
    $(this).text('Testing');
}
```

If that's not an option (for example, if you want to re-use that function, you can make it a parameter and use an anonymous callback that delegates to it:

```
$('#default').countdown({
    until: new Date(2011, 6, 15, 12, 30, 0),
    onTick: function(periods) { displayVariable(periods, 'Testing', 123); }
});

function displayVariable(periods, aVariable, aSecondVariable) {
    // do something with parameters
}
```

Comment: Very astute. I am using jQuery Countdown. The developer has been great thus far with responding to my questions on tweaking his script, but I think I used all me questions up with him.

Comment: Can't blame the guy. This isn't really a question about his plugin, it's a question about how to make JavaScript do what you want.

Comment: Exactly@Samir Talwar -- hence me being a novice. And that's why I turned to Stack Overflow. This site is the absolute best of all (forum-type) sites I have every used the in the past 10-12 years. I always get a solution and I generally get one within 2-30 minutes from posting.

Comment: @Samir Talwar -- on the surface it looks like your 2nd code snip might do what I need. I am going to test and I'll post back. Thanks so much for the suggestion.

Comment: @Samir Talwar -- I stand corrected. The subsequent function call already has a parameter defined to it. See my complete code posted herein

Comment: @Samir Talwar. Ok, I'll try that.

Comment: Forget Dr.Dot, this dude downvotes the _reasonable answers he received_ that don`t give the results he wants on half-posted questions. Mental note to myself to stay clear of this unappreciative newb.

Comment: Sorry if I upset you stef. Truly didn't mean any harm.

Comment: @Samir Talwar. It's late where I am at so I will test in morning and post back.

Comment: @Shamir Talwar. Your suggested code did not work (for me). My attempt to override the 'open source code' script's .text element did not work. The script rendered the .text that it normally does. My code is posted herein as an answer with label Code from Samir (no success for me). Thanks.

Comment: @Samir Talwar - just to add a comment as cleanup to this thread, I wanted to send the developer (lives in Australia) some money because his script was exactly what I was looking for and he stuck with me a few times to help me tweak his script (within it's confines) but he did not have a PayPal account.

Comment: @Seth and @stefgosselin -- re: down plusing, I do not know if S.O. penalizes a member's point accumulation or their profile rating if someone down pluses. Honestly, I don't understand a good portion of S.O.'s system behaviour (like why I can't get timely/instantaneous email alerts when someone responds to my posts -- they come to me about a week later, but that's another issue altogether) but I assure you I will never down plus again. I really meant no harm by doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you're not setting it as a normal variable?

```
var testVar_value = 'Testing';

$('#default').countdown({
    until: new Date(2011, 6, 15, 12, 30, 0),
    testVar: testVar_value,
    onTick: displayVariable
});

function displayVariable() {
    $(this).text(testVar_value);
}
```

Comment: Yes. The code is excerpted portions from the overall script. The displayVariable() function gets called from other parts of the script.

Comment: It would be handy if you could try to explain you case a bit more accurately, or show some actual code in place so we could understand your constraints.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how it works, you'll need to create a variable for that, not some object being passed to a different function.

Something like this would work:

```
var testVar = 'Testing';
function displayVariable() {
    $(this).text(testVar);
}
```

Or by using a object literal like so:

```
var literal = {
    testVar: 'Testing'
}

function displayVariable() {
    $(this).text(literal.testVar);
}
```

Comment: @Shaz...can I do either of those from within my $('#default').countdown({});  ?

Comment: @Dr. Dot: **Within** the object literal, no; but that's what I'm trying to explain. Create the `testVar` variable outside of the scope, or make `onTick` a function literal and do what you want there. `onTick: function() {var testVar = 'Testing';  $(this).text(testVar);}`

Comment: Sorry then..it won't get me what I ultimately need.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that displayVariable is not known within the context you are trying to call it from. 
If you really need the displayVariable function, you should do the following:

Note: testVar is defined in global scope

```
 $('#default').countdown({    
    until: new Date(2011, 6, 15, 12, 30, 0),    
    me: this,         
    onTick: function() { 
        me.testVar = 'blahdieblah';
        me.displayVariable();
 } });
```

Comment: This won't achieve my objective for reason(s) I posted as comments to the other similar solution

Comment: the code is excerpted portions from the overall script. The displayVariable() function gets called from other parts of the script, thus it must reside outside the $('#default').countdown({}); as I had it in my original question post.

Comment: I don't know what the global scope section should look like and then what the displayVariable() function should look like...so I technically unable make an attempt to test your solution given my level of familiarirty with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

**Code from aquinas (success for me)**

```
// Round #4 Start Times -- note each Date() must match the 'lockout' column in _playoff_bracket:matches 
$('#defaultCountdown_15').countdown({
    //until: new Date(2011, 6 - 1, 1, 20, 0, 0),
    until: new Date(2011, 5 - 1, 29, 7, 29, 0),
    //test: 'Testing',
    serverSync: serverTime,
    significant: 2,
    layout: 'This Pick Closes in: {d<}{dn} {dl} {d>}{h<}{hn} {hl} {h>}{m<}{mn} {ml} {m>}{s<}{sn} {sl} {s>}',
    expiryUrl: '/nhl/playoffs/myAccount.html',
    onTick: additionalFormatting
    //onTick: function(periods) { additionalFormatting(periods, 'This is a test'); } // Samir
//});
}).data("testVar","Test by aquinas"); // aquinas

// additional hightlighting for more than 1-day and within last-hour of pick
function additionalFormatting(periods) {
//function additionalFormatting(periods, textOverride) { // Samir
    if ($.countdown.periodsToSeconds(periods) >= 86400) {
        //$(this).text('You have until Wednesday at 8:00pm ET to finalize this pick');
        //$(this).text(textOverride); // this should come from Round #4 var Samir
        $(this).text($(this).data("testVar"));
        $(this).removeClass('hideIt');
        //$(this).addClass('hideIt'); // greater than or equal to 1-day (2011-05-28 changed this method for one above)
    }
    else $(this).removeClass('hideIt'); // less than 24 hours
    if ($.countdown.periodsToSeconds(periods) < 60) { // less than 1-minute
        $(this).addClass('highlightBold'); // change font-weight to bold
        //$(this).countdown('change', 'significant', 1); // eliminate minutes block -- does not work as I hoped for
        //$(this).countdown('change', 'layout', 'This Pick Closes in: {sn} {sl}'); // eliminate minutes block -- does not work either
    }
    else if ($.countdown.periodsToSeconds(periods) < 3600) $(this).addClass('highlight'); // less than 1-hour
}
```